# I'd like to send list to php file and save list to mysqli

Tags: java, php, httpurlconnection

Hi i'm trying to send course list which has more than 2,000 course info to mysqli through php file. but ! whenever i try to send list, it doesn't send it to server.
so can you help me to solve this problem..?  :(

First, java source

```
public static void sendCourseInfoToDB(List<Subject> subjects, String url) {

    try {
        // url is my *.php file 
        URL target = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) target.openConnection();

        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.setDoInput(true);
        con.setUseCaches(false);
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/html; charset = utf-8");

        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());


        int len = subjects.size();

        for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
            //String t = subjects.get(i).toString();
            out.writeBytes(subjects.get(i).toString());
            out.flush();
        }   

        out.flush();
        out.close();            

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("Post rqeust to Url : " + url);
        System.out.println("Post Params : " + subjects.get(0).toString());
        System.out.println("Resoponse Code : " + Integer.toString(responseCode));

        con.disconnect();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Subject class overrides toString. return-statement used parameter is encoded UTF-8
like this :

```
courseCode = 12156&courseName = %EC%8B%A0%EC%86%8C%EC%9E%AC%EA%B3%B5%ED%95%99%EB%B6%80&subjectName = %EC%A2%85%ED%95%A9%EA%B3%BC%EC%A0%9C%EC%84%A4%EA%B3%841&kindOfSubject = %EC%A0%84%EA%B3%B5&score = 2
```

and php file

```
<?php

header("Content-Type : text/html; charset = utf-8");

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "db");

if($mysqli->mysqli_errno) {
    print $mysqli_error;
    exit();
}

$courseCode = $_POST["courseCode"];
$courseName = $_POST["courseName"];
$subjectName = $_POST["subjectName"];
$kindOfSubject = $_POST["kindOfSubject"];
$score = $_POST["score"];

$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO COURSE VALUES('$courseCode', '$courseName', '$subjectName', '$kindOfSubject', '$score')");

$response = $courseCode;

echo $response;
?>
```

should i call 'sendCourseInfoToDB function every time when i send course info to DB ?  i dont know what is wrong.. help me crazy coding people~!~

Comment: you will create the new course and insert that into db using php and then do a subjects.add() to add a new item to the list in java and sendCourseInfoToDB is not required to be called

Comment: thank you ! I solve this problem..but use diffrent way. Anyway i really appreciate of your help !